# What can limit the plausibility of the Arabic "š-k-l"(ش ك ل) being in the same lineage as the German "gestalt" via its assumed PIE ancestor "*stel"?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, semitic-languages

They have near-fully overlapping meanings (I would be going out on a limb to say fully equivalent translations) with both the [Arabic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B4_%D9%83_%D9%84#Arabic) and [German](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gestalt#German) words having their primary use in expressing the meaning in "geometric shape" and also being analogous to the word *form* as in *Platonic forms* in their respective languages.

[Supposedly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/stel-) *stellen*, the original verb form of *gestalt*, descends from the Proto-Indo-European **stel*, which puts it at one t <-> k mutation away from the Arabic *š-k-l* (Or a shared ancestor with Hebrew *š-k-l-l* שכלל) based on examples like the [palatalization in Modern Arabic dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change)#Semitic_languages) or Egyptian as an example contemporary to PIE if [Loprieno p.31](https://books.google.com/books?id=kW8Mzji0XRgC) can be cited:

> [Proto-]Afroas[iatic] velar plosives *k, *g and 'k display two outcomes [...] either they are maintained as k [...] or they are palatalized into *t*, /c/ [...]

Also, mostly on pure fancy, I am interpreting the meanings conveyed in the cited [Ancient Greek](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AD%CE%BB%CE%BB%CF%89#Ancient_Greek) and [Slavic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/st%D1%8Clati) descendants from **stel* as containing the common conceptual element in grouping, bringing together, forming up etc. which can be a potential (even if very weak) indicator for **stel* having a meaning related to *form*.

So this is where the *too good to be true* principle kicks in for me to look for factors that make it implausible for these two to have a common origin. What are some venues to exhaust for evidence on the contrary before actually pursuing this claim further?

Comment: A couple notes: Loprieno is talking about ṯ, not t—Egyptian ṯ was something like IPA /c/ or /tʃ/, a palatal, not /t/, an alveolar/dental. I'm also not sure how Egyptian is "contemporary" with German; Egyptian is first attested around 3000 BCE, while Old High German isn't attested until close to 1000 CE.

Comment: I meant contemporary with Proto-Indo-European, will clarify. Also left a further speculative shift from a palatal t to a alveolar t implied for brevity's sake

Comment: Why not begin with the beginning: the Arabic ش [ʃ] [descends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitic_languages#Consonants) from the Proto-Semitic [ɬ]. How does that correlate with the PIE _s_? «The pronunciation of [Proto-Semitic] *ś ṣ́ as [ɬ ɬʼ] is still maintained in the Modern South Arabian languages (such as Mehri), and evidence of a former lateral pronunciation is evident in a number of other languages. For example, Biblical Hebrew _baśam_ was borrowed into Ancient Greek as _balsamon_ (hence English "balsam")» ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Semitic_language#Fricatives))

Comment: I am basing that off interpreting that Hebrew example I included as pointing to a Proto-Semitic ancestor word with a similar sound and meaning. Also I am being somewhat lenient with consonant mismatches with both German and Arabic having extensive histories with much more radical consonant shifts through millenia

Comment: (As a side note—props for looking into other cognates. Most people who ask "are these words related?" questions here don't do that, and it's an important part of determining relatedness.)

Comment: The Hebrew ש in _š-k-l-l_ שכלל “to improve” is a prefix, at least so says _A Comprehensive Etymological Dictionary of the Hebrew Language for Readers of English_, 1987, by Ernest Klein. It is a borrowing from Akkadian _shuklulu_ which is a Š-stem verb where _shu-_ is a prefix.

Comment: @YellowSky that sure adds an interesting place to look at, but I am a little cynical about this one. I could only find a single reference to that particular word and translation: on a Newberry 1934 referencing a [Muss-Arnolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Muss-Arnolt) 1903 dictionary (German-English-Assyrian).

Looking at his theological background and publication history, I am too suspicious about the interests or methodology involved to treat it as credible

Comment: Found a Cargill 2012, which instead puts Aramaic as the source language: "שכלל is the Shaphel pf. 3ms form of the Aramaic verb כלל, meaning to 'complete' or 'finish'"

Although the subject is TgNeof/Palestinian Aramaic, not sure how much of a difference it makes in the context

Comment: Ernest Klein writes that the Aramaic verb is also borrowed from Akkadian _shuklulu_. [Here's a scan](https://i.imgur.com/TrnuUT8.jpg) of the article in the dictionary I mentioned. [Here](http://www.assyrianlanguages.org/akkadian/dosearch.php) is _shuklulu_ in an online Akkadian-English dictionary.

Comment: @YellowSky I do not think "prob. borrowed from" was meant to be a citable reference. As for the *shuklulu* I hit a wall on that word with that 1903 Assyrian dictionary, unless there are alternate renditions I am missing. No Akkadian *shuklulu* on JSTOR so no credible reference

Comment: @YellowSky AssyrianLanguages' dictionary doesn't allow linking to individual entries unfortunately; Layman, go [here](http://www.assyrianlanguages.org/akkadian/search.php) and search for "cuklulu" (they use C for Š for ease of typing). You can also see ORACC's entry for the word [here](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/cams/selbi/cbd/akk-x-stdbab/akk-x-stdbab.x001452.html). Brown-Driver-Briggs (a classic reference work for Biblical Hebrew) says "perhaps loan-word from Assyrian šuklulu, ušaklil, uštaklil".

Comment: @Draconis and the trail for that "perhaps loan-word" ends with Muss-Arnolt as I mentioned

Comment: Ia! Ia! Shuklulu balsamon! In his binyan in Akkad, dead Shuklulu lies conjugating.

Comment: @RobertColumbia truly terrifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where am I getting too excited and overlooking things?

Occam's razor.

Many more German words came from Proto-Indo-European than from anything Afro-Asiatic, and there are plenty of cognates to *stellen* in other branches of Indo-European, as you cited (see also Old Latin *stlocus* "place, location"). So the hypothesis that *Gestalt* came from Proto-Indo-European is simpler and requires fewer assumptions.

When the languages in question were spoken so many thousands of years ago (and never written down), it's difficult to be certain of anything. So showing a relationship between proto-languages requires *enormous* amounts of evidence. For a single pair of words like this, Occam's razor suggests instead that it's just a coincidence.

(Could, instead, PIE **stel-* be borrowed from Proto-Afro-Asiatic or one of its descendants? Possibly; unfortunately, it would have happened so long ago that it's impossible to know for certain. The meanings and sounds aren't similar enough for me to put money on it, but there's also no way to definitively rule it out. So the best we can say about that is "not enough evidence to refute the null hypothesis".)

Comment: "Could, instead, PIE *stel- be borrowed from Proto-Afro-Asiatic" that is the conclusion I was pretty much daydreaming about. Not sure how I implied an Arabic origin though -- I was trying to imply the PIE word as being on the divergence point with some corresponding Proto-Semitic

Comment: @Layman In that case, you'll want to look at the reconstructed ancestor of the Arabic and Hebrew words; I don't know what that ancestor is, but Yellow Sky says it started with *ś (a lateral fricative /ɬ/), and *ɬ-k-l vs *stel is a bit of a stretch. The only thing they actually share in common is the final L.

Comment: @Layman The issue with that is, sound change tends to be regular and universal, which means we can see patterns in it. Proto-Indo-European *p at the start of words regularly became *f in Proto-Germanic, which is why we can see dozens and dozens of examples of correspondences where Latin/Greek/Sanskrit/etc has a word starting with P and English has a word starting with F (pater~father, pyr~fire, piscis~fish, etc). But this was a regular change that affected the entire language; P and F weren't and aren't just interchangeable ("pit" and "fit" mean totally different things).

Comment: @Layman It's possible that some Afro-Asiatic language or dialect could have turned *ś into S and *k into T, sure. But if so we'd expect to see those changes happen all across the language, not just in a single word.

Comment: According to Huehnergard 2019 p.50: The fricative *s may have had a palatalized allophone in some environments, since its reflex is a palatal [ʃ] in several of the languages (Babylonian Akkadian, Hebrew, Aramaic, Jibbāli), rather than [s] as in Assyrian Akkadian, Arabic and Ethiopian Semitic

Comment: Seems *ś-ɬ and k-<ins>t</ins> are both plausible as allophone pairs with some backing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113502/discussion-between-draconis-and-layman).

Comment: Rephrased the question FYI in case you'd like to edit out the quoted bit I removed from the post

Comment: "Many more German words came from Proto-Indo-European than from anything Afro-Asiatic" is a premisses fit for circular reasoning, a truism by definition. "the hypothesis that Gestalt came from Proto-Indo-European is simpler" You can't use a comparative to deny the comparison. That's paradox like: color sleeps *more* furiously. "... requires fewer assumptions." Deriving everything ex nihilo requires fewest assumptions. Beyond that it's not clear how you would enumerate irrational arguments like PAA or pre-PIE. "When the languages in question were spoken" If! Your faith is strong as ever.

Comment: @vectory Feel free to do a corpus or lexicon analysis and see how many German words are said to be of Indo-European vs Afro-Asiatic origin. And it's absolutely possible say that one hypothesis is simpler (or requires fewer assumptions) than another. That's the whole point of Occam's razor. You can derive everything ex nihilo if you want, but you still have to explain the observed data, and correspondences like Grimm's Law become _wildly_ implausible if every Indo-European language appeared fully-formed out of nowhere. And there's nothing inherently irrational about pre-PIE; it's just hard…

Comment: …to say anything definite about what came before it. (But quite a few scholars have speculated about e.g. the pre-PIE phonological system, for example, to explain some of the typological oddities in the usual reconstruction.)